# Getting EntityTooSmall Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3

I am trying to download data from Azure blob in chunk and then trying to upload same chunk to aws s3 bucket. 
While uploading I am getting `"Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size"`exception. One thing I noticed, in upload response I am getting 0 content length. Data size I am trying is more than 300MB.
Any pointers what could be wrong here? 
Below is my code snippet :

```
            var remainingLength = blob.Properties.Length;
            long startPosition = 0;
            List<UploadPartResponse> uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();
            int i = 1;
            string uploadId = string.Empty;

            //Step 1: build and send a multi upload request
            var initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = existingBucketName,
                Key = "firstobj"
            };

            var initResponse = client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initiateRequest);
            uploadId = initResponse.UploadId;

            do
            {
                var blockSize = Math.Min(segmentSize, remainingLength);
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    blob.DownloadRangeToStream(ms, startPosition, blockSize);

                    //Step 2: upload each chunk (this is run for every chunk unlike the other steps which are run once)
                    var uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = existingBucketName,
                        Key = "firstobj",
                        UploadId = uploadId,
                        PartNumber = i,
                        PartSize = ms.Length,
                        InputStream = ms
                    };

                    // Upload part and add response to our list.
                    var temp = client.UploadPart(uploadRequest);
                    uploadResponses.Add(temp);
                }

                //Step 3: build and send the multipart complete request
                if (blockSize < segmentSize)
                {

                    var completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = existingBucketName,
                        Key = "firstobj",
                        UploadId = uploadId,
                    };

                    completeRequest.AddPartETags(uploadResponses);    
                    client.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest);
                }

                startPosition += blockSize;
                remainingLength -= blockSize;
                i++;
            }
            while (remainingLength > 0);
```

Comment: What is the segment size/block size you're trying to upload in S3?

Comment: @GauravMantri Its 50 MB

Comment: On which line in your code are you getting the error?

Comment: @GauravMantri client.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest); throws error

Comment: `PartSize = ms.Length`?  That doesn't seem right.  This seems like it should be `PartSize = blockSize`, doesn't it?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I tried your suggestion but same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After banging my head a lot, I got solution for this. It was in step 2 just before uploading part to AWS we should set stream position to 0.

```
uploadRequest.InputStream.Position = 0;
```